# Proving that the expectation is always negative

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am interested in if the expected value $$E_{X_3}\left[\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\right]<0$$ is always be **negative** or not. Here, I have $3$ random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$, corresponding to the densities $f_1,f_2,f_3$ with their Cumulative distribution functions satifying $F_1(Y)>F_2(Y)>F_3(Y)$.

If I rewrite the expectation, I have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_3(y) \log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\mathrm{d}y$$

If I take the expectation with respect to $X_1$ then I have $$E_{X_1}\left[\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\right]>0$$

If I take the expectation with respect to $X_2$ then I have $$E_{X_2}\left[\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\right]<0$$

due to stochastical ordering ${X_3}_{ST}>{X_2}_{ST}>{X_1}_{ST}$ since $F_1(Y)>F_2(Y)>F_3(Y)$ I suppose that I must have $$E_{X_3}\left[\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\right]<0$$

do you have any ideas how I can prove this?

Thanks for your help.

**Additional Information**: If $F_1(Y)>F_2(Y)>F_3(Y)$ then $E[X_3]>E[X_2]>E[X_1]$

Answer (score 1):

*(These are remnants of a wrong try... Finding a case when $I>0$ is still open.)*

If $X_i=\frac{X}{a_i}$ with $X$ standard exponential and $a_3\lt a_2\lt a_1$, then $f_i(x)=a_i\mathrm e^{-a_ix}$ on $x\gt0$ hence
$$
\log\left(\frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}\right)=\log\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2}\right)-\left(a_1-a_2\right)\,x,
$$
and the expectation sought for is
$$
I=E\left(\log\left(\frac{f_1(X_3)}{f_2(X_3)}\right)\right)=\log\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2}\right)-\frac{a_1-a_2}{a_3}.
$$
Thus,
$$
I\lt\log\left(\frac{a_1}{a_2}\right)-\frac{a_1-a_2}{a_2}\lt0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much did. I just saw it. Let me read..

Comment: It seems this is a counter example to my previous question.

Comment: I tried something like this: $a_1=1$, $a_2=1.1$, $a_3=1.2$ and I got something negative. If $a_3\rightarrow a_1$ for some fixed $a_1$, $a_1<a_2<a_3$ does not hold. Do I have a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I made a mistake. Sorry about that. Finding a case when $I\gt0$ is still open.

Comment: Thanks alot once again. This problem is a simplification of the previous one with $f_1=g_1$. I would only guess that it should be negative because $X_3$ is dominating $X_2$ and under $X_2$, we already have something negative. Just intuition is that it can only be a bit more negative.

Comment: I have an idea about it and I will post as an answer soon. I will be happy if you could comment on it.thx)

Answer (score 0):

For some ${X_3}_{ST}>{X_2}_{ST}>{X_1}_{ST}>0$, I claim that $$E[X_3^N]>E[X_2^N]>E[X_1^N],\quad N\geq 1$$ For $X_3=a_3X$, $X_2=a_2X$, $X_1=a_1X$, with $a_3>a_2>a_1$ it is obvious. For the general case I have no proof about it. For the moment, I can only suppose that It also holds for the general case.

Based on this assumption I can create any positive function $g_i$ as some linear combinations of $X_i$, $i=1,2,3$.

$$\int_{\Omega}f_3(X_3)\{a_1X_3^N+a_2X_3^{N-1}...\}\mathrm{d}\mu>\int_{\Omega}f_2(X_2)\{a_1X_2^N+a_2X_2^{N-1}...\}\mathrm{d}\mu>\int_{\Omega}f_1(X_1)\{a_1X_1^N+a_2X_1^{N-1}...\}\mathrm{d}\mu$$

Applying this to the logarithm function $$\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}$$ we have $$\int_{\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}>1}f_3(y)\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\mathrm{d}y>\int_{\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}>1}f_2(y)\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\mathrm{d}y>\int_{\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}>1}f_1(y)\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\mathrm{d} y$$

Similarly we have

$$\int_{\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}<1}f_1(y)\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\mathrm{d}y>\int_{\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}<1}f_2(y)\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\mathrm{d}y>\int_{\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}<1}f_3(y)\log\frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\mathrm{d} y$$

For the conlusion I was thinking about combining both and perhaps if necessary to use Jensen's inequality. Am I on the right track or do i have problems even at the start where I did the assumption?

Comment: The claim at the beginning, involving $E[X^N]$ for $X\geqslant0$, is true, for a reference see any textbook on the coupling method. Unfortunately, later on it is not true that $E[u(X_3)]\geqslant E[u(X_2)]$ and the like (what you need just after "$i=1,2,3$") for every function $u$. Stochastic domination of $X$ by $Y$ implies (and in fact is equivalent to) $E[u(X)]\leqslant E[u(Y)]$ for every **nondecreasing** $u$.

Comment: I didnt understand very much why the following should be incorrect. I have simply Tailor expansion of a positive function. May be you mean I need some terms with some negative coefficients to represent any positive function? if $f_1/f_2$ is for example linear decreasing can I have a Taylor serier expansion with purely positive coefficients?

Comment: @Did "textbook on coupling method" I didnt find some good references via google search. Could you please suggest me some textbook(s) on this issue? I will be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: The book *Lectures on the coupling method* by Torgny Lindvall and/or some [Lecture notes](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/probability/lecturenotes/CouplingLectures.pdf) on the subject by Frank den Hollander.